# How to set a radio-button label to 'checked'?

Tags: css, radio-button, label

I've a total of three radio buttons for a tiny rating. As I don't like 'normal' radio buttons, I'm using font-awesome icons instead. How can I mark them as checked, when a user clicks on one of these:

```
<input id="rate-bad" name="rate" type="radio" value="bad" tabindex="5">
<label class="choice" for="rate-bad"><i class="fa fa-frown-o fa-3x"></i>bad</label>
```

The input button is set to invisible.

Is there something like 'choice::checked' that can be used?

Comment: Check this out - http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk/

Comment: Thanks Luis P.A. - this made my day: input[type=radio]:checked + label {
 color:#000;
}

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with jquery.

for example

```
<input id="rate-bad" name="rate" type="radio" value="bad" tabindex="5">
<label id="bad" class="choice" for="rate-bad"><i class="fa fa-frown-o fa-3x"></i>bad</label>
```

jquery:

```
$("#bad").click(function() {
   $("#rate-bad").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value="" checked="checked" />
```

this will help you in making the radio button checked